# Outputting floating numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just starting to learn Python (2.7) and I have a question.

First my code:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

number_a = float(raw_input())
number_b = float(raw_input())

add(number_a, number_b)
```

As you can see I want to ask the user to give me 2 floating numbers and then add them and print the solution. But when I put in 2 floating numbers, they are still printed as rounded numbers. How do I get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%f` for floats. You can adjust decimal precision using `%.2f` for 2 digits or `%.3f` for three digits, etc.

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %.2f + %.2f" % (a, b)
    return a + b

number_a = float(raw_input())
number_b = float(raw_input())

add(number_a, number_b)
```

Answer (score 2):

`%d` formats a **d**ecimal integer. `%f` formats a **f**loat:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %f + %f" % (a, b)
    return a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float format string `%f` instead of integer `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use formatting sequence for floats, not integers, so this:

```
print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
```

should be:

```
print "ADDING %f + %f" % (a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING {0} + {1}".format(a, b)
    return a + b

>>> add(1, 2)
ADDING 1 + 2
3
>>> add(1.5, 3)
ADDING 1.5 + 3
4.5
```